# Why didn't the while-Loop become an endless one and why did the loop seem to be asynchronous?

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop, sleep

```
def main():
    interval=datetime.timedelta(microseconds=250)
    for i in range(1200000,1400000):
    #for i in range(1300000,1300010):
        start=datetime.datetime.now()
        end=start+interval
        print(start)
        fetch(i)
        realend=datetime.datetime.now()
        while realend<=end:
            time.sleep(end-realend)
        i+=1
main()
```

Here is the code, partial of a spider, aimed to make 4 requests per second. As you can see, the while-Loop, which is seemingly an endless loop, worked fairly well actually. It did work at the speed of 4 requests per second constantly. (I didn't even realize the issue.) I do think it very strange. The realend and end haven't been changed, why would the condition of the while statement change?
The working environment is Python3.11, HomeBrew, macOS 13.1 x64.

```
def main():
    interval=datetime.timedelta(microseconds=250)
    for i in range(1200000,1400000):
    #for i in range(1300000,1300010):
        start=datetime.datetime.now()
        end=start+interval
        print(start)
        fetch(i)
        while datetime.datetime.now()<=end:
            time.sleep(0.000001)
        i+=1
main()
```

The original version of the code is here. It seems ridiculous to use the while here, I admit. But the result it returned was fairly interesting: the fetching speed was nearly one request per second, making me suspect Python worked in an asynchronous pattern. (It ought to be done in 0.25s but actually it done in nearly 0.5~1s in the halfway, while the pattern above to calculate the actual sleeping time worked fairly well, so I guess that Python made a lot of signals before the loop actually done, as if an asynchronous one.) That is also an issue.

fetch method is:

```
import datetime
import time
import requests
import bs4
import sqlite3
def wget(UA,url,tid):
    try:
        cache=requests.get(url,headers=UA,timeout=6.05)
        cache.raise_for_status()
        cache.encoding=cache.apparent_encoding
        return cache.text
    except:
        print("[DEBUG]:Failed to fetch tid %d."%tid)
        return ""
def modify(cache,tid):
    try:
        soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(cache,"html.parser")
        result=soup.prettify()
        return result
    except:
        print("[DEBUG]:Failed to modify tid %d."%tid)
        return ""
def export(page,tid):
    database=sqlite3.connect("post-cache1.sqlite3")
    c=database.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts(tid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, content MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL)")
    try:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO posts VALUES (?,?)",(tid,page))
        database.commit()
        database.close()
    except:
        print("[DEBUG]:Failed in executing database for tid %d."%tid)
        database.close()
def fetch(tid):
    UA={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Safari/605.1.15"}
    url="https://****/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=%d"%tid
    print(url)
    origin=wget(UA,url,tid)
    mod=modify(origin,tid)
    export(mod,tid)
```

So can anyone tell me why would the first one work and why did the second loop seem to be asynchronous?

Comment: This code is a bit weird to me. In addition to what you've written, there's no need to increment i, since it gets done by the for loop.

Comment: i don't see any reason why the while loop should be an endless one. I sleeps until it reaches the desired "end" time.
But i agree on "this could have been cleaner!" :D

Comment: What is fetch?  You need to post a complete working sample.

Comment: I doubt that your OS provides a sleep that accurate.  time.sleep(0.000001).  That probably resolves to 0.001 s.

Comment: 200,000 * 0.001 is 200 seconds which is a long time

Comment: A 250 microsecond delay would be 4000 requests per second, not 4.  If you're actually getting around 4 per second, then your `fetch()` must be taking a quarter of a second on average.

Comment: That's right, it's my fault. Thanks for your help. XD